# How to get the client´s screen resolution in an interception context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I just intercept the client´s request using global.asax's `Application_BeginRequest` method to know if it is coming from **ZZZ** url to know if it should redirect to **YYY** or **XXX** page, depending its screen resolution.

I read some posts/articles saying that to get the screen resolution I need to get it first by JavaScript.

**Problem**

As I´m in an interception context (the client may not walk by a page before), how to get the client´s screen resolution ?

Answer (score -2):

You can't. There is no standard that specifies something like that.
What I have done in the past is used JavaScript to obtain the screen/window size and store the values in an hidden field. Not exactly what you are looking for, but I imagine it's the only possible answer, IMO.